# Blazor WebAssembly publish failed

Tags: visual-studio, iis, blazor, publish

I'm trying to publish a Blazor WebAssembly App, targeting .NET 5.0.
I created a new Web Deploy publish profile from Visual Studio 2019, using the default settings:

[image]

The site is published to IIS, but the browser is displaying a 500.19 - Internal Server Error: "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

[image]

There's a strange path for web.config, which is starting with "\\?\":

```
\\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\__ClientBlazor\web.config
```

I've tried any of the suggestions I've found on similar threads, but none of them solve the problem.
Could it be a specific bug of VS publish wizard on Blazor projects?

Comment: It's called .NET 5, not ".NET framework 5.0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that it was an url-rewrite problem, which is addressed by this IIS [Url Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) extension.
Simply install the extension and the republish the app, it will work.

BUT other errors will then be raised, like the following:
404 on every css and javascript resources (see [this](https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/how-to-deal-with-the-http-404-content-foo-bar-css-not-found-when-using-razor-component-package-on-asp-net-core-blazor-app-aai) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827912/blazor-base-tag-and-page-instruction-in-razor-files) for further details and a really weird solution).