# Blazor webassembly (net5.0) publish not worked in IIS

Tags: iis, .net-5, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have created a Blazor webassambly net5 project with Identity Server (asp.net core hosted, PWA checked). Project run fine development in Visual Studio and done publish with it. Publish file is in ProjectName/Server/bin/release/net5.0/publish.

I followed the steps to host on IIS as,

- From windows features, enabled IIS features (show in image)
- Restarted the windows
- Asp net **core hosting bundle 5.0.7** downloaded and installed
- Restarted the windows
- added site on IIS, pointing to the publish folder , **"ProjectName/Server/bin/release/net5.0/publish"**, and **Port 801**
- In application pool, .NET CLR Version is set to **'No Managed Code'**
- But the site is not working, and the message is
  `This page isn’t working right now localhost can't currently handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`.

Here I have attached some images I have done,
[image]

Server .csproj file.
[image]

IIS setup and Program Features
[image]

used application pool
[image]

and the result, while browse the site
[image]

I have tried some other answers/result from search but not success.
Please help.

Comment: Can you run a report and see if anything is missing? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110243/blazor-webassembly-publish-failed

Comment: Hmm.... Weird. Have you tested to check your error logs? I follow steps on this post https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-publish-asp-net-core-blazor-application-to-iis/ and it is working flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I finally got success to run. I figured out as it was due to IdentityServer Setting. To solve, SelfSignedCertificate is created and followed appropriate "key" setting under IdentityServer in appsettings.json.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Blazor Team its [suggested Web.config](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly/_samples/web.config?raw=true)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31726464)