# Make a global variable for baseURI available in every view/component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In my blazor server app, I have to face varying base-URIs when running my app on my production server compared to my local developer machine.

For example, in production my app would be available via http://mydns/Goodwill/

whereas on my developer machine, it would be available via http://localhost:port/ (without the Goodwill)

I was trying to figure out how to deal with that problem and i came up with the following solution:

```
baseURI = NavigationManager.BaseUri.Split("/")[3];
        if (baseURI.Contains("Goodwill"))
            baseURI = "/Goodwill";
        else
            baseURI = "";
```

If i deploy my code on the production server, baseURI will be "/Goodwill", but it will be an empty string when I run the app locally. In the second step, I have to replace all the navigation links in my app with that baseURI prefix, e.g.:

```
<a class="nav-link active" href="@baseURI/Goodwill">Index</a>
```

The problem is that I don't know where/how to put that above code to make it available in every view/component that I have. I don't want to have that code in every view that I create, but the baseURI variable should be available.

I tried to place it in the MainLayout.razor:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<header>
  <NavMenu />
</header>
<body>    
    @Body   
    <BlazoredToasts />
</body>

<footer class="footer mt-auto py-0 bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted"> &copy; 2021 - Merbag S.A.</span>
    </div>
</footer>
@code{
    public string baseURI;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {  
        baseURI = NavigationManager.BaseUri.Split("/")[3];
        if (baseURI.Contains("Goodwill"))
            baseURI = "/Goodwill";
        else
            baseURI = "";
    }
}
```

But I can't access the variable in all my other views.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66401599/3411327)

Comment: Good stuff, that helped me!